# Dynamically adding a textview not working

Tags: android, json, textview

I have the following code in a main.xml file and a rows.xml file.
main.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Time">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Module">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Lecturer">
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

    </TableLayout>
```

rows.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:gravity="center" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/module"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lecturer"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I want to add a textview with the day of the week every 8 rows (starting with 0). I can add the textview if I want the textview added to the main.xml file, but if I put the same code in the rows.xml file (and removing it from the main.xml file), the app won't work (no errors come up but eclipse brings up the debug tab with the following:)

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1651    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1667 
    ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 117   
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 935   
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 130 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3687    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 867  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 625 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
Thread [<8> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
Thread [<7> Binder Thread #1] (Running)
```

Where am I going wrong and how can I fix it?

EDIT:
Logcat

```
01-18 02:44:14.656: W/ActivityThread(893): Application com.example.timetable is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-18 02:44:14.664: I/System.out(893): Sending WAIT chunk
01-18 02:44:14.882: I/System.out(893): Debugger has connected
01-18 02:44:14.882: I/System.out(893): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 02:44:15.078: I/System.out(893): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 02:44:15.281: I/System.out(893): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 02:44:15.484: I/System.out(893): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 02:44:15.679: I/System.out(893): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 02:44:15.898: I/System.out(893): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 02:44:16.093: I/System.out(893): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-18 02:44:16.296: I/System.out(893): debugger has settled (1410)
01-18 02:44:16.476: I/ApplicationPackageManager(893): cscCountry is not German : VDI
```

Code for dynamic textview

```
View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);

int a = 0;  
while(x < 41)
{
            //The textview is only printed out every 8 rows because there is only 8 classes a day and the day is printed out at the start
    if(x == 0 || x == 8 || x == 16 || x == 24 || x == 32)
    {

            TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
            valueTV.setText(fetch2.get(a)); //fetch2 has the days of the week stored in it
            valueTV.setId(x);
            valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            a++;

        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV); 
        x++;
    }
    else
    {
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.id.listview, fetch); //fetch has the time, module and lecturer stored
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        x++;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Main.java

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class Main extends Activity {
private ListView lv;
private CustomAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Custom> fetch = new ArrayList<Custom>();
private ArrayList<String> fetch2 = new ArrayList<String>();
private int x = 0;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    fetch2.add("Monday");
    fetch2.add("Tuesday");
    fetch2.add("Wednesday");
    fetch2.add("Thursday");
    fetch2.add("Friday");


    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.timetable);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int ctr;
    try {
        ctr = inputStream.read();
        while (ctr != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(ctr);
            ctr = inputStream.read();

        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        //Parse the data into jsonobject to get original data in form of json.  
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());

                    //Grabs the data for each day
        JSONArray Monday = jObject.getJSONArray("Monday");
        JSONArray Tuesday = jObject.getJSONArray("Tuesday");
        JSONArray Wednesday = jObject.getJSONArray("Wednesday");
        JSONArray Thursday = jObject.getJSONArray("Thursday");
        JSONArray Friday = jObject.getJSONArray("Friday");

        String time= "";
        String module = "";
        String lecturer = "";

                    //Adding each days data
        for (int i = 0; i < Monday.length(); i++) 
        {
            time = Monday.getJSONObject(i).getString("time");
            module = Monday.getJSONObject(i).getString("module");
            lecturer = Monday.getJSONObject(i).getString("lecturer");
            Custom a = new Custom(time, module, lecturer);
            fetch.add(a);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Tuesday.length(); i++) 
        {   
            time = Tuesday.getJSONObject(i).getString("time");
            module = Tuesday.getJSONObject(i).getString("module");
            lecturer = Tuesday.getJSONObject(i).getString("lecturer");
            Custom a = new Custom(time, module, lecturer);
            fetch.add(a);
        }       
        for (int i = 0; i < Wednesday.length(); i++) 
        {
            time = Wednesday.getJSONObject(i).getString("time");
            module = Wednesday.getJSONObject(i).getString("module");
            lecturer = Wednesday.getJSONObject(i).getString("lecturer");
            Custom a = new Custom(time, module, lecturer);
            fetch.add(a);
        }   
        for (int i = 0; i < Thursday.length(); i++) 
        {
            time = Thursday.getJSONObject(i).getString("time");
            module = Thursday.getJSONObject(i).getString("module");
            lecturer = Thursday.getJSONObject(i).getString("lecturer");
            Custom a = new Custom(time, module, lecturer);
            fetch.add(a);
        }   
        for (int i = 0; i < Friday.length(); i++) 
        {
            time = Friday.getJSONObject(i).getString("time");
            module = Friday.getJSONObject(i).getString("module");
            lecturer = Friday.getJSONObject(i).getString("lecturer");
            Custom a = new Custom(time, module, lecturer);
            fetch.add(a);
        }               

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);

    int a = 0;  
    while(x < 41)
    {
                    //The textview is only printed out every 8 rows because there is only 8 classes a day and the day is printed out at the start
        if(x == 0 || x == 8 || x == 16 || x == 24 || x == 32)
        {       
            TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
            valueTV.setText(fetch2.get(a));
            valueTV.setId(x);
            valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            a++;

            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV); 
        }
        else
        {
                    //Adding each days data
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.id.listview, fetch);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            x++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you show me the logcat error log?and your code for dynamically add,so maybe I can know where your code go wrong :)

Comment: There is no logcat error, but I have added that and the code for the dynamic textview.

Comment: where is LinearLayout with View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have any linear layout with id info so when the program trying to find it in here

```
View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);
```

The code will break

You try to access listview `@+id/info` from your code but in your code in the `onCreate` you set the content view to `R.layout.main` so the code will try to find `@+id/info` in the main.xml and the code won't find it because you declare it in the rows.xml, the solution is you can try to add the rows.xml dynamically (using inflater) or the way I prefer to create another view with java files that extends table layout (or another layout and create your own `TableLayout`)and add another view dynamically using `view.addView`.

Here's a simple example for you (the example extends `LinearLayout`)

```
public class ChildMyBadge extends LinearLayout {

private Context context;
private ChildTopModel contentModel;

public ChildMyBadge(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ChildMyBadge(Context context, ChildTopModel contentModel) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    this.contentModel = contentModel;
    LayoutParams lpMyBadge = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpMyBadge.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    this.setLayoutParams(lpMyBadge);
    this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    initView();
}

private void initView() {

    LinearLayout llContainerInfo = new LinearLayout(context);
    llContainerInfo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,Util.getDisplayWidth(context)/20) );
    llContainerInfo.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    TextView tvInfo = new TextView(context);
    LayoutParams lpInfo = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpInfo.setMargins(Util.getDisplayWidth(context)/100, Util.getDisplayWidth(context)/100, 
            Util.getDisplayWidth(context)/100, Util.getDisplayWidth(context)/100);
    tvInfo.setLayoutParams(lpInfo);
    tvInfo.setText(R.string.MyBadgeInfo);
    tvInfo.setTextSize(7);

    llContainerInfo.addView(tvInfo);
    this.addView(llContainerInfo);
    ArrayList<Integer> temp_friend_id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> friend_id = contentModel.getFriend_id();
    Log.i(BaseID.TAG, "Size : " + friend_id.size());
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        temp_friend_id.add(friend_id.get(i));
    }
    Log.i(BaseID.TAG, temp_friend_id.toString());
    this.addView(new ChildMyBadgeRow(context,1,temp_friend_id));
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        temp_friend_id.clear();
        for(int i=(8+j*6);i<(14+j*6);i++)
        {
            temp_friend_id.add(friend_id.get(i));
        }
        Log.i(BaseID.TAG, temp_friend_id.toString());
        this.addView(new ChildMyBadgeRow(context, 2,temp_friend_id));
    }
    }
}
```

You can see I'm adding my row dynamically and every row will also add the cell dynamically so the process will be:

mainview constructor -> looping how many row and add row -> everytime row constructor called -> looping how many cells will be added

I hope you understand my explanation at least why your code gives you the error.

Comment: When I change the ListView to LinearLayout the same thing happens, it does work when I put it in the main.xml file but doesn't (the debug tab comes up) when I put it in the rows.xml file

Comment: I still can't find where you place @+id/info in your xml?

Comment: My apologies, I had it called day by mistake (only on here, in eclipse I had it as info.

Comment: OK so can I know where you declare this View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info); ? is it same with when you setContentView(R.layout.rows) ? or can you edit your question and add more code?

Comment: OK now I figured why your code break, please see my edited answer :)

Comment: I think I can understand you code, but I don't know why my code isn't working. I'm not getting why when I have @+id/info in the main.xml file the list view will work (Monday - Friday will print to the screen), but if I put @+id/info in the rows.xml file it breaks.

Comment: I already explained that above, you try to access @+id/info (member of rows.xml) but you now only accessing main.xml, as you can see you haven't accessed rows.xml in the main.java so you cannot do this View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info); because the code will try to find @+id/info in the main.xml :)

Comment: After thinking about it more, I think I know what you are saying.
I should see how many rows there will be in total (45, 8 classes a day + Monday - Friday) and in each row, how many cells it should have (1 or 3 depending on the row, row 0 will have 1 cell and every 9th row after it, the rest will have 3 cells). I don't suppose you would do it for me? (I didn't think so :P). I'm not quiet getting this.addView(new ChildMyBadgeRow(context,1,temp_friend_id)); what is the 'context' and '1'? I'm fairly new at java and android. I'm going try give it a try myself and hope for the best.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was working on the post for a while and didn't see your post above it until I posted it. Would it be easier to try copy what you have done or try get the code to access the rows.xml to get the @+id/info? Or would it be possibly/easier to do what I want to do with only the main.xml file?

Comment: about context you can get more information about it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html and '1' is parameter I requested from the childmybadgerow constructor if you want to copy what I have done you must understand the concept of adding view in android programatically